# Can we have race conditions in a single-thread program?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, race-condition

You can find on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) a very good explanation about what is a race condition.

I have seen recently many people making confusing statements about race conditions and threads.

I have learned that race conditions could only occur between threads. But I saw code that looked like race conditions, in event and asynchronous based languages, even if the program was single thread, like in Node.js, in GTK+, etc.

Can we have a race condition in a single thread program?

Comment: A single threaded program may exhibit weird behaviors if there is reentrancy issues due to callback. Maybe not "race condition" in the strict sense.

Comment: Yes, this would probably fit it the "weird but determined" category. If you can provide a canonical example, I would be happy to turn my question to community wiki.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

*All examples are in a fictional language very close to Javascript.*

Short:

1. A race condition can only occur **between** two or more threads / external state (one of them can be the OS). We **cannot** have race conditions inside a single thread process, non I/O doing program.
2. But a single thread program can in many cases :

   1. give situations which looks similar to race conditions, like in event based program with an event loop, but **are not real race conditions**
   2. trigger a race condition between or with other thread(s), for example, or because the execution of some parts of the program depends on external state :

      1. other programs, like clients
      2. library threads or servers
      3. system clock

## I) Race conditions can only occur with two or more threads

A race condition can only occur when two or more threads try to access a shared resource without knowing it is modified at the same time by **unknown instructions** from the other thread(s). This gives an **undetermined result**. (This is really important.)

A single thread process is nothing more than a sequence of **known instructions** which therefore results in a **determined result**, even if the execution order of instructions is not easy to read in the code.

## II) But we are not safe

### II.1) Situations similar to race conditions

Many programming languages implements asynchronous programming features through *events* or *signals*, handled by a *main loop* or *event loop* which check for the event queue and trigger the listeners. Example of this are Javascript, libuevent, reactPHP, GNOME GLib... Sometimes, we can find situations which seems to be race conditions, **but they are not**.

The way the event loop is called is always **known**, so the result is **determined**, even if the execution order of instructions is not easy to read (or even cannot be read if we do not know the library).

Example:

```
setTimeout(
  function() { console.log("EVENT LOOP CALLED"); },
  1
); // We want to print EVENT LOOP CALLED after 1 milliseconds

var now = new Date();
while(new Date() - now < 10) //We do something during 10 milliseconds

console.log("EVENT LOOP NOT CALLED");
```

in Javascript output is **always** (you can test in node.js) :

```
EVENT LOOP NOT CALLED
EVENT LOOP CALLED
```

because, the event loop is called when the stack is empty (all functions have returned).

Be aware that this is just an example and that in languages that implements events in a different way, the result might be different, but it would still be determined by the implementation.

### II.2) Race condition between other threads, for example :

#### II.2.i) With other programs like clients

If other processes are requesting our process, that our program do not treat requests in an atomic way, and that our process share some resources between the requests, there might be a race condition *between clients*.

Example:

```
var step;
on('requestOpen')(
  function() {
    step = 0;
  }
);

on('requestData')(
  function() {
    step = step + 1;
  }
);

on('requestEnd')(
  function() {
    step = step +1; //step should be 2 after that
    sendResponse(step);
  }
);
```

Here, we have a classical race condition setup. If a request is opened just before another ends, `step` will be reset to 0. If two `requestData` events are triggered before the `requestEnd` because of two concurrent requests, step will reach 3. *But this is because we take the sequence of events as undetermined.* We expect that the result of a program is most of the time undetermined with an undetermined input.

In fact, if our program is single thread, **given a sequence of events** the result is still always determined. The race condition is **between clients**.

There is two ways to understand the thing :

- We can consider clients as part of our program (why not ?) and in this case, our program is multi thread. End of the story.
- More commonly we can consider that clients are not part of our program. In this case they are just **input**. And when we consider if a program has a determined result or not, we do that with **input given**. Otherwise even the simplest program `return input;` would have a undetermined result.

Note that :

- if our process treat request in an atomic way, it is the same as if there was a *mutex* between client, and there is no race condition.
- if we can identify request and attach the variable to a request object which is the same at every step of the request, there is no shared resource between clients and no race condition

#### II.2.ii) With library thread(s)

In our programs, we often use libraries which spawn other processes or threads, or that just do I/O with other processes (and I/O is always undetermined).

Example :

```
databaseClient.sendRequest('add Me to the database');

databaseClient.sendRequest('remove Me from the database');
```

This can trigger a race condition in an asynchronous library. This is the case if `sendRequest()` returns after having sent the request to the database, but before the request is really executed. We immediately send another request and we cannot know if the first will be executed before the second is evaluated, because database works on another thread. There is a race condition **between the program and the database process**.

But, if the database was on the same thread as the program (which in real life does not happen often) is would be impossible that sendRequest returns before the request is processed. (Unless the request is queued, but in this case, the result is still **determined** as we know exactly how and when the queue is read.)

#### II.2.i) With system clock

@mingwei-samuel answer gives an example of a race condition with a single thread JS program, between to `setTimeout` callback. Actually, once both `setTimeout` are called, the execution order is already determined. This order depends on the system clock state (so, an external thread) at the time of `setTimeout` call.

## Conclusion

In short, single-thread programs are not free from trigerring race conditions. But they can only occur **with or between other threads of external programs**. The result of our program might be undetermined, because the input our program receive from those other programs is undetermined.

Comment: A very good post! But in my opinion a race condition must not based upon multiple threads. According to the meaning of the word there only has to be a special situation in which the result of an operation depends on the execution of individual operations. By simulating threads using different priorities we could introduce such situations. Therefore I would like to call them race conditions as well, even if it is wrong according to the definition.

Comment: "According to the meaning of the word there only has to be a special situation in which the result of an operation depends on the execution of individual operations" That is a really crappy definition. By that definition, every app is a race condition because it needs to load resources in a certain order, process user input in a certain order, display things in a certain order, etc.

Comment: *I) Race conditions can only occur with two or more threads* Not quite true.  A signal handler interrupts an existing thread asynchronously.  [IBM example code, non re-entrant functions doesn't work in my system](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/562477) is an example of a race condition between the main program and a signal handler, leading to C data race UB in a single-threaded C program.  Also note that C++11 std::atomic has separate `atomic_signal_fence` vs. `atomic_thread_fence` functions, in case you only need ordering wrt. accesses by a signal handler in the current thread.

Answer (score 3):

Race conditions can occur with any system that has concurrently executing processes that create state changes in external processes, examples of which include :

- multithreading,
- event loops,
- multiprocessing,
- instruction level parallelism where out-of-order execution of instructions has to take care to avoid race conditions,
- circuit design,
- dating (romance),
- real races in e.g. the olympic games.

Comment: In cpu architecture / out-of-order exec, we call them "hazards", not "race conditions to be avoided".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture).  Clever answer but that one is a bit of a stretch.  You could include signal handlers, which are asynchronous but run in the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes.

A "race condition" is *a situation when the result of a program can change depending on the order operations are run (threads, async tasks, individual instructions, etc).*

For example, in Javascript:

```js
setTimeout(() => console.log("Hello"), 10);
setTimeout(() => setTimeout(() => console.log("World"), 4), 4);

// VM812:1 Hello
// VM812:2 World

setTimeout(() => console.log("Hello"), 10);
setTimeout(() => setTimeout(() => console.log("World"), 4), 4);

// VM815:2 World
// VM815:1 Hello
```

So clearly this code depends on how the JS event loop works, how tasks are ordered/chosen, what other events occurred during execution, and even how your operating system chose to schedule the JS runtime process.

This is contrived, but a real program could have a situation where "Hello" needs to be run before "World", which could result in some nasty non-deterministic bugs. How people could consider this not a "real" race condition, I'm not sure.

#### Data Races

It is not possible to have data races in single threaded code.

A "data race" is *multiple threads accessing a shared resource at the same time in an inconstant way,* or specifically for memory: *multiple threads accessing the same memory, where one (or more) is writing*. Of course, with a single thread this is not possible.

<s>This seems to be what @jillro's answer is talking about.</s>

---

Note: the exact definitions of "race condition" and "data race" are not agreed upon. But if it looks like a race condition, acts like a race condition, and causes nasty non-deterministic bugs like a race condition, then I think it should be called a race condition.

Comment: My answer is about race condition being impossible in single threaded process when no external state is involved. Clock is an external state.

Single threaded event loops without timeout and reliance on system clock are always deterministic and cannot have race condition.

Comment: Signal handlers aren't a separate thread but they can create data races.  [IBM example code, non re-entrant functions doesn't work in my system](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/562555)

Answer (score 0):

Sure can. Disk I/O runs asynchronously. If you fire off disk IO and go do something else and fire off more disk IO you can eventually fill the hardware's internal command queue and get a "no" back. Gotta handle the disk IO hasn't finished by the time you want to do more disk IO even if the data rates say you have ten times as much time as you need.

Source: I have an SD card with a slow spot. Writing to it takes many times longer than expected. I lost a race condition.

Comment: Disk I/O runs asynchronously... because they run in another process.

Comment: @jillro: You know about DMA transfers right? On modern hardware disk IO runs in no process until it finishes.

Comment: Running on hardware controller doesn't mean it runs in no process. Just not on main CPU.