# messages publish before subscribe in core.async

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, core.async

In the following example I can see, that published messages arrive to the subscribed channel, although, they are published before subscription is made.

```
(let [in (async/chan)
      out (async/chan)
      pub (async/pub in :key)]

  (async/go
    (>! in {:id 1 :key :k1})  
    (>! in {:id 2 :key :k1})  
    (>! in {:id 3 :key :k1}))

    (async/sub pub :k1 out)

    (async/go-loop []
      (println (<! out)) 
      (recur)))
```

Is this expected behavior? As far as I can see in the documentation, it clearly states:

> *Items received when there are no matching subs get dropped.*

I get same results in both Clojure and ClojureScript.

Added:
   with mult/tap I see similar behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't know that the messages are published before the subscription is made. Because go is asynchronous, it's very possible that the subscription happens before the first message has been put into the channel. It's a race condition, really.

Try putting a `(Thread/sleep [some value])` before the suscription and see what happens.

Comment: You still don't know the order of execution of the statements. See this post for clarification. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463377/can-we-have-race-conditions-in-a-single-thread-program

Comment: now i slightly changed the code and placed everything into one big (go ..). same result. my understanding is that everything inside (go ..) is computed sequentially.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by "everything in one big go." Can you post your code, perhaps in a separate question?

Comment: It is here - https://gist.github.com/aav/2d8117a70574db9c3729 - I assume that everything inside (go ...) is computed sequentially.

Comment: Interestingly this code (from the gist) behaves different in Clojure and ClojureScript. In Clojure it works as expected, and in ClojureScript still delivers messages to the subscribing channel.